# Mongo $near query takes 6s on 1.2 millions documents

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, geospatial, bigdata, database

I inserted about 1.2 millions identical documents for testing speed of geospatial index in MongoDb

Here is a query:

```
db.spreads.find({ loc: { '$near': { '$geometry': {type: "Point" , coordinates: [40,40]}, '$maxDistance': 10000000 } } }).explain();
```

And result

```
{
    "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1568220,
    "nscannedObjects" : 12545154,
    "nscanned" : 12545154,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 12545154,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 12545154,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 11413,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "s1.heychat.io:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Indexes:

> db.spreads.getIndexes();

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.spreads"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "loc" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "loc_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "test.spreads",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

Why so slowly?

Comment: have you defined proper index for your collection?

Comment: Yes, 2dsphere for loc field

Comment: As I know there no way to make $near without geo index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"n" : 1568220` in the explain output means that the query returned 1.5 million docs. So that would explain why it took so long.

Using a much smaller `$maxDistance` is probably a better test.

Comment: I've tried maxDistance 100 and it took 5981 milliseconds. It's still very slowly. Can be the reason, that all documents have the same coordinates in collection?

Comment: If all the documents have the same coordinates then a spatial search will either return zero or all your records and becomes a bit pointless (no pun intended).

Comment: But it really works. maxDistance 1 took 3sec. Thank you!